# How to get the last integer ID you query in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to get the last ID input that I query in MySQL Database.

**Note:** The itemid is auto increment and of type integer.

In this example, I want to get the last item query, which is itemcode 13.

Here is the screenshot of the table:

[image]

Comment: What does "queued" mean?

Comment: 'Quered'? 'Queued'? What is this question about?

Comment: I've corrected your title (mis-edited by other hands), to agree with your content edit, but there is no such word as 'quered'. Please clarify, by which  I mean please use an existing English word that will be unambiguously understood.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() as last_id from table limit 0,1");
    lastid = rs.getString("last_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, the nested queries retrieves the maximum itemcode and then filter the main query in order to fetch the row.

```
select * from table_name where itemcode = (select max(itemcode) from table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to retrieve the maximum value of `itemcode`. Use `MAX` operator. result will be `13`.

```
select max(itemcode) from table_name.
```